# "Cache invalid, retry (internally handled)" reported by System Settings -> Backups

Tags: backup

When running a backup using System Settings -> Backups, the Back Up dialog box reports "Cache invalid, retry (internally handled)." I did not see any obviously relevant details in journalctl. What actions should I take to debug this error?

Comment: Reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1711750